# Update DOM reference in jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, reference

I am modifying an elements `innerHTML` property inside a `$.each()` loop. Now if my stack of elements contains childrens of the element where I update the `innerHTML`, the DOM reference of that children will get lost.

Example:

```
$(function(){
    $stack = $(".myelement, .myelement *");
    $stack.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var element = $(this)[0];
        console.log(element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + " modified");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0ux0v5e/

What happens is that I first modify the `innerHTML` of `.myelement`. This includes the children `p`. Therefore the DOM reference of this element is get lost and "modified" will not be appended.

How can such an scenario be solved without building a function that creates a unique selector for the element and re-catches it in each loop?

Note: I am not asking for specifically appending some text to nodes. This is just an example. In a real project I am replacing text in the `innerHTML`.

Comment: I guess you need a nested each loop.

Comment: is it not already working in the fiddle?

Comment: Only `.myelement` gets appended with `modified` because the something happens with the `.each` reference to the p-element. So the child elements wont actually get the modified text appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify innerHTML, it will destroy/recreate all the elements inside and force a re-render. You can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) or jQuery's [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add to an element.

Also you do not need to do:

```
element = $(this)[0];
```

`this` will already be a reference to the element.

```js
$(function(){
    $stack = $(".myelement, .myelement *");
    $stack.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //this.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend"," modified");
        //Or
        $this.append(" modified");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
  <span>A span</span>
  <div>A div</div>
  <div>
    <p>a paragraph in a div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

As it seems you want to replace word(s) and not append a word, you could do a `replace` on the html and then reset it, but again this will destroy/recreate the elements inside, so if any of them have something like event listeners attached they will be lost

```
var modified = $".myelement").html().replace(/yourword/g,"modified");
$(".myelement").html(modified);
```

Or you could just loop over all the Text nodes and replace the word from there, this will keep the elements, their event listeners, and so on intact.

```js
$(".myelement, .myelement *").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){
  this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/A/g,"modified");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
  Inside A element <br>
  <span>A span</span>
  <div>A div</div>
  <div>
    <p>a paragraph in A div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Unfortunately this doesn't help me because I would like to replace, not append something. However, this may be helpful for others who want to append.

Comment: @julmot, Replace it with what? You said _"and 'modified' will not be appended"_ if the elements are not supposed to have "modified" appended to it what are you wanting to actually happen?

Comment: Well, in a real project I am replacing a word in the innerHTML with something else.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that, as is, your question seems to be attempting at just add something to the end, not replace a word in it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to modify the text content. in this case you would like to know about `.contents()` method, which lets you loop through with text nodes as well:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".myelement").contents().each(function(i, el) {
    el.textContent += " 'modified'";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
  I am the myelement
  <p>
    Hello world
  </p></div>
```

Comment: `textContent` seems to be the correct thing, rather than `innerHTML`. Thank you, Jai.

Answer (score -1):

just change

```
 $stack = $(".myelement, .myelement *");
```

to

```
 $stack = $(".myelement");
```

And you will see in your console

```
I am the myelement
<p>
    Hello world
</p> modified
```

Comment: Sorry, you didn't understand my question.